# Scroll view when character reaches border

Tags: scroll, cocos2d-x

I'm making a game similar to Mario. At the moment my character can walk left and right and cannot go further when it reaches the border. Now, I want the view to scroll when the character is x amount of pixels away from the border. It shouldn't scroll just horizontally, but vertically as well.

At the moment I have 1 class that extends cclayer. This class draws a sprite and blocks. I have searched where to go from here, but I haven't really found anything useful/up to date. 
So would be great if someone has some tips.

Also, in the mentioned class I also create a box2d world with gravity. If I have to make multiple layers do I create multiple box2d worlds for each layer?

Comment: You can try Parallax examples in Cocos2dx TestCpp project. Also you can just create 2 layers one for background and other for character. When character reaches near end of one side you can either decrease or increase X component of background layer position accordingly your character direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  CCFolow action. This follow a node. Example:

```
CCSprite * hero = CCSprite::create("hero.png");
CCLayer * gamelLayer = GameLayer::create();
CCFollow *follow = CCFollow(hero, CCRect(0, 0, 4056, 3062));
gameLayer->runAction(follow);
```

When you change position of hero, the gameLayer move too, but always we see on the screen fragment of CCRect(0, 0, 4056, 3062). In this situation you don't need to use Scrolview, but normal CCLayer.